# How to simplify an expression with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have a matrix of the form:

```
Tvol // TraditionalForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \frac{\delta  I_1(\kappa )}{I_0(\kappa )} & 0 \\
 \frac{I_1(\kappa ) \delta ^*}{I_0(\kappa )} & \frac{\delta  (I_1(\kappa )+\kappa  I_2(\kappa )) \delta ^*}{\kappa  I_0(\kappa )} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\delta  I_1(\kappa ) \delta ^*}{\kappa  I_0(\kappa )} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

That I want to simplify with these assumptions:$g=\frac{I_2(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)},g_c=\frac{I_1(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)}$
So far I have tried the following codes, but none of them work.

```
Replace[Tvol, 
  {BesselI[2, κ]/BesselI[0, κ] -> g, 
   BesselI[1, κ]/BesselI[0, κ] -> Subscript[g, c]}]

Refine[Tvol, 
  Assumptions -> 
    {g = BesselI[2, κ]/BesselI[0, κ], 
     Subscript[g, c] = BesselI[1, κ]/BesselI[0, κ]}]

Simplify[Tvol, 
  Assumptions -> 
    {g = BesselI[2, κ]/BesselI[0, κ], 
     Subscript[g, c] = BesselI[1, κ]/BesselI[0, κ]}]
```

The definition of $Tvol$ is as follows:

```
Tvol = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
Tvol[[1, 1]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[1, 1]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[1, 2]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[1, 2]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[1, 3]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[1, 3]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[2, 1]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[2, 1]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[2, 2]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[2, 2]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[2, 3]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[2, 3]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[3, 1]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[3, 1]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[3, 2]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[3, 2]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
Tvol[[3, 3]] = Integrate[p[ψ, 0, κ]*T[ψ][[3, 3]], {ψ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

$T(\psi)$ and $p(\psi)$ are earlier defined in the notebook as follows:

```
S = Sqrt[2]/2*{{1 + δ\[Conjugate], 0}, {0, 1 - δ\[Conjugate]}} // Simplify  
k = 
  (1/Sqrt[2]) *
    {{S[[1, 1]] + S[[2, 2]]}, {S[[1, 1]] - S[[2, 2]]}, {2 S[[1, 2]]}} // Simplify  
Subscript[T, 0] = Dot[k, ConjugateTranspose[k]] // Simplify  
R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}  
T[ψ_] := Dot[R[ψ], Subscript[T, 0], Transpose[R[ψ]]]  
p[x_, mu_, k_] := 2*PDF[VonMisesDistribution[2 mu, k], 2 x] // Simplify;
```

---

Following the comments I wrote:

```
Simplify[Tvol, 
  Assumptions -> 
    {g == BesselI[2, κ]/BesselI[0, κ], 
     Subscript[g, c] == BesselI[1, κ]/BesselI[0, κ]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, (δ BesselI[1, κ])/BesselI[0, κ], 0}, 
>  {(BesselI[1, κ] Conjugate[δ])/BesselI[0, κ], 
>   (δ (BesselI[1, κ] + κ BesselI[2, κ]) Conjugate[δ])/(κ BesselI[0, κ]), 
>   0}, 
>  {0, 0, (δ BesselI[1, κ] Conjugate[δ])/(κ BesselI[0, κ])}}
> ```

but as you see that didn't solve the problem. I even replaced `,` by `&&`:

```
Simplify[Tvol, 
  Assumptions -> 
    {g == BesselI[2, κ]/BesselI[0, κ] && 
     Subscript[g, c] == BesselI[1, κ]/BesselI[0, κ]}]
```

but that does not change the result.

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you provide your definition of `Tvol`.

Comment: The problem is, your assumptions are not boolean statements. Use a `==` sign (double equals). The single `=` sign has another meaning in MMA. Thus I vote to close as "arising from a syntax error"

Comment: @LLlAMnYP that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I agree, it's not only because of the syntax error. Alexei has provided a solution, but from your definition of `Tvol` it's not entirely obvious to me, why Alexei's result is wrong.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438730/what-is-the-solution-of-the-integral-in-terms-of-bessel-functions) is the other form of `Tvol` @LLlAMnYP

Comment: I see. In your link it seems quite obvious, that Mathematica's result is "simpler". Of course, given your substitutions, it may be even better to use the result provided by the authors of the article, but there's no straightforward way to make MMA realize, that there's a nice relationship between `g` and `gc` that will let it simplify to what you want. I'm pretty sure, there's a way to use the `TransformationFunctions` option to teach it, but I can't help much further. I suggest you check out the many other threads on simplification here.

Comment: Incidentially, I've retracted my "close" vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
    Tvol /. 
      {BesselI[1, κ] -> gc*BesselI[0, κ], BesselI[2, κ] -> g*BesselI[0, κ]} // 
        Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

??

Later edit: to deal with the complex conjugated deltas you may do as follows:

```
 Tvol /. 
   {BesselI[1, κ] -> gc*BesselI[0, κ], BesselI[2, κ] -> g*BesselI[0, κ]} /. 
     δ*a__*δ\[Conjugate] -> a*Abs[δ]^2 // Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: It should be $$\begin{bmatrix}1&g_c\delta&0\\g_c\delta^*&\frac{(1+g)}{2}|\delta|^2&0\\0&0&\frac{(1-g)}{2}|\delta|^2\end{bmatrix}$$ after simplification

Comment: the element $(3,3)$ is $\frac{(1-g)}{2}|\delta|^2$. I don't why I can't edit it in the matrix

Comment: @sepideh I cannot really understand all your definitions, but it seems that you did not instruct Mma that δ∗ is a conjugated value of δ. Using simply a conjugate symbol is not enough. You should use `Conjugate[δ] ` instead and then apply `ComplexExpand ` in the end. In the case at hand you may go around easier by making a substitution `δ->Abs[δ]^2/δ∗ `after all the operations I did, but before the application of `TraditionalForm `. Have fun!

Comment: OK that is a problem but the more important problem for the time being is that, from the identity $I_1(\kappa)=\frac{\kappa}{2}(I_0(\kappa)-I_2(\kappa))$, the fraction in the elements $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ of the matrix will take another form: $$\frac{I_1(\kappa)+\kappa I_2(\kappa)}{\kappa I_0(\kappa)}=\frac{\frac{\kappa}{2}(I_0(\kappa)+I_2(\kappa))}{\kappa I_0(\kappa)}=\frac{I_0(\kappa)+I_2(\kappa)}{2I_0(\kappa)}=\frac{1+\frac{I_2(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)}}{2}=\frac{1+g}{2}$$

Comment: $$\frac{I_1(\kappa)}{\kappa I_0(\kappa)}=\frac{\frac{\kappa}{2}(I_0(\kappa)-I_2(\kappa))}{\kappa I_0(\kappa)}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{I_2(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)})=\frac{1-g}{2}$$ The problem is `mathematica` doesn't use this identity to give the result of `Tvol` in the other form and I don't know if I can use identities and get the other form or not before simplification. Your simplification is true based on what `mathematica` gives for `Tvol` but there should be a way to force `mathematica` use the identity $I_1(\kappa)=\frac{\kappa}{2}(I_0(\kappa)-I_2(\kappa))$ and then use your answer.

Comment: I'll ask another question for this issue

Comment: @sepideh Mma does use such identities. There has once been a discussion about it on this site, have a look. Generally, you might use `FullSimplify `instead of `Simplify`for that. However, the result depends upon the Mma "opinion", of what form of the expression is more simple. It does not always coincide with my own opinion. For this reason I would instead take the identities into account by making substitutions of the sort I did above, but based on my own ideas of how the result should look like.

Comment: Could you provide the link of that discussion?

Comment: @sepideh No, I will need to search through this site, but this you could do as well. I looked, however, into my records and see that the work with such identities typically requires a trick, such as the use of certain `TransformationFunctions `or of a special `ComplexityFunction `. Though very elegant, a direct substitution of a sort I did above might be faster to find.