# How to instruct mathematica that $\delta^*$ is the conjugate of $\delta$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, symbols

I have this code:

```
S = (Sqrt[2]/2)*{{1 + Conjugate[δ], 0}, {0,1 - Conjugate[δ]}}(**   Suppose a+b=1 and δ=((a-b)/(a+b))\[Conjugate]   **)
k = (1/Sqrt[2])*{{S[[1, 1]] + S[[2, 2]]}, {S[[1, 1]] - S[[2, 2]]}, {2 S[[1, 2]]}} // Simplify
Subscript[T, 0] = Dot[k, ConjugateTranspose[k]]
Subscript[T, 0] // MatrixForm
Subscript[T, 0] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \delta  & 0 \\
 \delta ^* & \delta  \delta ^* & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

As you see at the end the product of $\delta$ and $\delta^*$ is not printed as $|\delta|^2$ but as $\delta\delta^*$
Someone told me [in one of my questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94837/30689) that this is because:

> It seems that you did not instruct Mma that δ∗ is a conjugated value
>   of δ. Using simply a conjugate symbol is not enough. You should use
>   Conjugate[δ] instead and then apply ComplexExpand

so far I have tried several ways like
[Using the UpsetDelayed operator in the begining of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875374/is-there-a-way-to-make-mathematica-treat-a-symbol-as-real) as:

```
δ\[Conjugate] ^:= Conjugate[δ]
```

or using:

```
ComplexExpand[Subscript[T,0], δ, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Conjugate}]
```

But I couldn't change any thing?!

---

Following the [the first answer posted to the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94910/30689) I wrote:

```
FullSimplify[Subscript[T, 0]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \delta  & 0 \\
 \delta ^* & \left| \delta \right| ^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
But when I continue the code and apply the same trick on another matrix, the trick doesn't work!

```
R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}
T[ψ_] := Dot[R[ψ], Subscript[T, 0], Transpose[R[ψ]]]
FullSimplify[T[ψ]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \delta  (\cos  (2 \psi )) & -\delta  (\sin  (2 \psi )) \\
 \delta ^* (\cos  (2 \psi )) & \delta  \delta ^* \left(\cos ^2 (2 \psi )\right) & -\frac{1}{2} \delta  \delta ^* (\sin  (4 \psi )) \\
 -\delta ^* (\sin  (2 \psi )) & -\frac{1}{2} \delta  \delta ^* (\sin  (4 \psi )) & \delta  \delta ^* \left(\sin ^2 (2 \psi )\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I am genuinely surprised, that MMA, treating all symbols as complex quantities by default, does not automatically convert `d d*` to `Abs[d^2]` or `Abs[d]^2`, however there is a sort of explanation to this. IIRC, MMA judges the complexity of an expression by its `LeafCount`. Both `d d*` and `Abs[d]^2` (as well as `Abs[d^2]`) have a `LeafCount` of `4`, so I *guess*, it feels no need to "simplify". I completely agree, that it is frustrating.

Comment: It may actually have its uses in matrix multiplication or the application of operators, where multiplication/order of application is non-commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything else fails, you always can write an explicit substitution rule

```
subc = {x_ Conjugate[x_] -> Abs[x]^2};
```

And apply it to your expression

```
FullSimplify[T[\[Psi]]] /. subc // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
FullSimplify@Subscript[T, 0] // TraditionalForm
```

does the trick.

Comment: thanks it solved so there's no need to instruct anything just `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify`. Mathetica itself knows that $\delta^*$ is the conjugate of $\delta$ and so can simplify!